# Change background image of listview on item selected from adapter

Tags: android

In my getView method from my listadapter, When i select an item in the list, i want this selected item background image to take a specific image and the other items from the list to take the default background image. I implemented a for loop to do this but when i select an item from the row, the background image doesn't change.. can we change background image from a button click ? and where am i wrong because i believe my code is ok. Here is the part where the selected item is checked.

pos = position;

```
    size = main.items.size()-1;

    holder.row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int x = position + 1;

               for (int i=0;i<size;i++){

                   holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_unselected);

                   holder.text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                   if (x==main.items.size()-1){

                       holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_selected);

                       holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                   }    

               }

               System.out.println("selected layer: "+ x );

               System.out.println("selected layer pos: "+pos);

               System.out.println("selected layer size: "+size);


               main.selectItem(position+1);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_unselected);
holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layer_selected);
```

With

1. For Button Background

   ```
   holder.row.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_unselected));
   holder.row.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_selected));
   ```
2. For ImageView Background

   ```
   holder.row.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_unselected));
   holder.row.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_selected));
   ```

Comment: i use           holder.row.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_unselected));
 it has no effects dear

Comment: don't use v.getResources(). Use only getResources()

Comment: when i use getResources() it say "The method getResources() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}"

Comment: can you tell me the type of holder.row.e.g Button,Layout etc

Comment: its an imageview and a textview in the middle

Comment: For ImageView Use setImageBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_‌​unselected));

Comment: holder.row.setBackgroundDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_selected));

Comment: inside the view i put two condition on the imageview do you believe this might conflict with the button click ?

Comment: use this may work holder.row.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer_s‌​elected));

Comment: yes it worked but how to change the text now it should be black when i click on it. it remains white

Comment: tell me the type of holder.text

Comment: use holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); doesn't work holder.text is a textview

Comment: you can do this without coding. use selector. see my last answer.I'm using that and it work fine for me

Comment: have you try this holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000") has no effect

Comment: "#000000" code black color and "#ffffff" code for white color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24954/discussion-between-kirit-and-sophia)

Answer (score 0):

MyListAdapter

```
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

    private List<HashMap<String,String>> List;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int layoutresource;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<HashMap<String, String>> myList) {
        List = myList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        layoutresource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return List.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutresource,null);
        }    

        final View rootView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);

        Button btnFav = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFav); 
        MyTextView name = (MyTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        MyTextView variety = (MyTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textVariety);
        MyTextView price = (MyTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPrice);

        btnFav.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.remove_fav_button_selector));
        name.setText( List.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
        variety.setText(List.get(position).get(TAG_VARIETY));
        price.setText(List.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE));

        rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("ID", List.get(position).get(TAG_ID));
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff8800"/>
 <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff8800"/>
 <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="@color/textColor"/>
<!-- default -->

</selector>
```

main.xml

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="Button"
       android:textColor="@drawable/text_color_selector" />
```